# Create IAM account with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to create an AWS IAMS account that has various permissions with CloudFormation.

I understand there are policies that would let a user change his password and let him get his account to use MFA [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124786/aws-cloudformation-enable-mfa?newreg=9d07e7c9d733438b82b483b8a6afe541)

How could I enforce the user to use MFA at first log in time when he needs to change the default password?

This is what I have:

The flow I have so far is:

1. User account is created
2. When user tries to log in for the first time is asked to change the default password.
3. User is logged in the AWS console.

Expected behavior:

1. User account is created
2. When user tries to log in for the first time is asked to change the default password and set MFA using Authenticator app.
3. User is logged in the AWS console and has permissions.

A potential flow is shown [here](https://pomeroy.me/2020/09/solved-first-time-login-problems-when-enforcing-mfa-with-aws/). Is there another way?

Update:

This [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-delegate-management-of-multi-factor-authentication-to-aws-iam-users/) explains the flow
Again, is there a better way? Like an automatic pop up that would enforce the user straight away?

Update2:

I might have not been explicit enough.
What we have so far it is an ok customer experience.
This flow would be fluid

1. User tries to log in
2. Console asks for password change
3. Colsole asks for scanning the code and introducing the codes
4. User logs in with new password and the code from authenticator
   5.User is not able to deactivate MFA

Comment: I'd go with Balu's solution, the AWS SSO service is working pretty well. You can also create a custom-made solution with a Lambda Function that is triggered on an hourly basis, or even by a CloudTrail events such as  `ChangePassword` and `CreateUser`. It would be tough to implement and it's better off going with an out-of-the-box solution (AWS SSO). But still, if you wish to go in the custom-made solution path, I'll share more details of how I'd go

Comment: Who is Mark? :D. I think using AWS would be ok. Where is the solution?

Comment: And this what happens when you try to do multiple things at the same time :) I meant Balu

Comment: hah. thanks for taking the time. I did leave a comment on his post. if you got the time

Comment: If your're using GSuite then here you go - How to use G Suite as an external identity provider for AWS SSO - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-g-suite-as-external-identity-provider-aws-sso/

Comment: Regarding your comment - there's no need to create a CloudFormation stack or anything if you use AWS SSO. The "force MFA" is applied from the identity provider (idP) side. For example- The user navigates to AWS Console > Redirected to idP (Google) > User login with credentials + MFA serial > Redirected to AWS Console.

Comment: @MeirGabay good to know about G-Suite. At the moment I am not using that. Will look in to implementing for the future, sounds interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the way to go and one could extract the knowledge of creating users with whatever permissions he wants after the user sets up the MFA.

The policy template it is useful.

[instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-delegate-management-of-multi-factor-authentication-to-aws-iam-users/)

Answer (score 0):

Allow users to self manage MFA is the way to go, if you are using regular IAM. You can try AWS SSO, it's easier to manage and free.

Allowing users to login, change password, setup MFA and Denying everything other than these if MFA is not setup as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_mfa-selfmanage.html)

We could create an IAM Group with an inline policy and assign users to that group.
This is CF for policy listed in the docs.

```
Resources:
  MyIamGroup:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Group
    Properties:
      GroupName: My-Group
  MyGroupPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy
              - iam:GetAccountSummary
              - iam:ListVirtualMFADevices
              - iam:ListUsers
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: "*"
          - Action:
              - iam:ChangePassword
              - iam:GetUser
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - "arn:"
                  - Ref: AWS::Partition
                  - :iam::1234567891111:user/${aws:username}
          - Action:
              - iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice
              - iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - "arn:"
                  - Ref: AWS::Partition
                  - :iam::1234567891111:mfa/${aws:username}
          - Action:
              - iam:DeactivateMFADevice
              - iam:EnableMFADevice
              - iam:ListMFADevices
              - iam:ResyncMFADevice
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - "arn:"
                  - Ref: AWS::Partition
                  - :iam::1234567891111:user/${aws:username}
          - NotAction:
              - iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice
              - iam:EnableMFADevice
              - iam:GetUser
              - iam:ListMFADevices
              - iam:ListVirtualMFADevices
              - iam:ListUsers
              - iam:ResyncMFADevice
              - sts:GetSessionToken
            Condition:
              BoolIfExists:
                aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent: "false"
            Effect: Deny
            Resource: "*"
      PolicyName: My-Group-Policy
      Groups:
        - Ref: MyIamGroup
```

Comment: you gave user the right to deactivate the MFA. he can go in, activate the MFA, bypass the rules and deactivate it after. I didn't try that yet, but wouldn't that work?

Comment: the moment MFA Is not setup, last statement will Deny everything. `iam:DeactivateMFADevice` and `iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice ` are required when users wants to change mfa device I believe

Comment: about to test your solution. if i am satisfied I will approve your answer, if not I will put my answer